# Android Chrome 121.0.6167.102 breaks my reactjs site

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-chrome

My [football simulator site](https://football.simcups.com) is broken on my POCO M5 phone like in the screenshot below after updating Android Chrome to 121.0.6167.102. The UI elements just breaks as scrolling down the fixtures. You can check out the recording of this issue at https://youtube.com/shorts/96-83oynNhs?feature=shared

The site uses reactjs and mantine. I have another old RedMi phone that uses 121.0.6167.101 and it has no issues at all. Clearing chrome cache doesn't fix it. Do you know what changes in chrome causing this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue, where multiple pages were broken in the new Chrome. Do you have by any chance the *cast player* (https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/cast-player/dionggdmdobjjolppiiejleechniphok?hl=en-GB&utm_source=ext_sidebar) extension in Chrome? I removed this extension and it looks ok.

Comment: Hello, I don't have it. It only happens on chrome on that specific phone model. Even chrome Beta and Dev versions do not work. I installed Opera and it works perfectly.